# oembed_dataparse filter not running at all for standard YouTube embed

Tags: filters, oembed

I need to wrap a div around all YouTube embeds in posts on our WP site.

- WordPress version is **4.9.6**
- The posts in question are WooComerce products
- Videos are being embedded by simply pasting a YouTube url in the post content.

In the code below `lr_setup_embed_plugin()` is definitely called because renaming that function causes an error, but the `oembed_dataparse` filter apparently isn't running because `oembed_youtube_add_wrapper()` is not called.

I have tried putting this code in functions.php and also in a plugin.

```
function oembed_youtube_add_wrapper($html, $data, $url) {

    if ($data->provider_name == 'YouTube') {
        return "<div class='whatever'>{$html}</div>";
    } else {
        return $html;
    }
}


function lr_setup_embed_plugin(){
  add_filter('oembed_dataparse', 'oembed_youtube_add_wrapper', 0, 2);
}


add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'lr_setup_embed_plugin' );
```

Comment: It's probably not the issue, but you shouldn't need the `lr_setup_embed_plugin()` function at all. You only need the `oembed_youtube_add_wrapper()` function and the `add_filter()`.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I had it without the `after_setup_theme` action wrapper to start with (which didn't work) and read somewhere that filters had to be added after theme setup otherwise they would have no effect.

Comment: Maybe in rare cases for a specific filter or two, that I can't think of, but as a general rule that is not accurate. Generally you should add filters as early as possible. Usually the only instances that you'll need to defer an action like this is if you want to _remove_ an action. You can only remove actions after they're added, so you'll often have to remove them from within another hook that runs later.

Comment: OK good to know. Well in either case `oembed_dataparse` is not running my function despite there being a YouTube URL in the post content that is being automatically converted to an embedded IFrame.

I solved it in 5 minutes with a jQuery workaround, but WordPress is just stubbornly refusing to cooperate.

Comment: I just copied your code exactly and it worked just fine. The YouTube embed is wrapped in a div with the class `whatever`.

Comment: There must be something else specific to this website stopping it from working. Very intermittently I am getting an error that the number of arguments passed to `oembed_youtube_add_wrapper*()` is wrong. Caching is definitely off (deactivated the caching plugin). I will remove things until I find out what's going on.

Comment: as far as I Unserstand, there ist a Cache in WordPress for oEmbeds. They are writen into the post_meta. IT needs top be cleard. See comments in the documentation.